# Getting Today and Yesterday in Date and String Format via VBA

Tags: vba, string, date

I'm struggeling to format my date strings correctly as it appears to be minusing the wrong parts of my date using `DateAdd` and I'm not sure how to resolve.

Eg:

```
Sub DateTest()
 DateStr = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
 Yesterday = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, CDate(DateStr)), "DD-MM-YY")
 YtdStr = Format(Yesterday, "DD-MM-YY")
 
 Debug.Print DateStr
 Debug.Print Yesterday
 Debug.Print YtdStr
End Sub
```

Result:

```
13-09-20
19-09-13
13-09-19
```

Expected Result:

```
13-09-20
12-09-20
12-09-20
```

I even tried using just "day of year" as this is for an `hidden report`, but I like using regular date strings I think or at least I'd like to get both figured out, but using day of year showed me some interesting results. Yesterday had to be `d 0` which made no sense, but if I used `-1` it removed two dates. As well, turning that into a string seems to remove another day?

Eg:

```
Sub DateTest()
 DateStr = Format(Date, "Y")
 YtdDate = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, CDate(DateStr)), "Y")
 YtdStr = Format(YtdDate, "Y")
 
 Debug.Print DateStr
 Debug.Print YtdDate
 Debug.Print YtdStr
End Sub
```

Resut:

```
257
256
255 'This was expected to be a string 256?
```

Can anybody point out how to format this correctly?

Comment: You are formatting the source date as string using `DD-MM-YY`, parse it back to date using your current system default date format (apparently `MM-DD-YY`), add days to the result of that, and format it back to string. Why all the intermediate formatting to strings?

Comment: My code uses strings and dates depending, eg for creating a worksheet I use string form as date form uses '/' which is unacceptable format

Comment: Dates do not have slashes. They are binary values. You operate with them as binary values, and only format the final result as string for display purposes.

Comment: Really try creating a Worksheet using a Date type variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are formatting the source date as string using `DD-MM-YY`, parsing it back to date using your current system default date format (apparently `MM-DD-YY`), adding days to the result of that, and formatting it back to string. You don't want these intermediate formatting to strings.

```vb
Sub DateTest()
  Dim DateNotStr As Date
  Dim YesterdayNotStrEither As Date

  DateNotStr = Date
  YesterdayNotStrEither = DateAdd("d", -1, DateNotStr)
  
 
  Debug.Print Format$(DateNotStr, "dd-mm-yy")
  Debug.Print Format$(YesterdayNotStrEither , "dd-mm-yy")
End Sub
```

Comment: Uhm... Yes I do want them as strings as well.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers You want the *end result* as strings. Which you have here.

Comment: Well, I need both to be correct and stored as variables. Some I use as Str and some a `Date`. I will just accept your answer, but your comment helped me figure it out. The "real" reason is I believe that my system does NOT use the format of `DD-MM-YY`. So `CDate` wasn't transformming my `DateStr` correctly. But, when I used my code w/ `Td = Date()` then passed that to `DateAdd` it worked correctly.

Comment: For example, I create the worksheet w/ `DateStr` but I compare to find yesterdays ws using `Date` as a `Date` not `Str`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Like I said, all manipulations must be done with dates, not with their string representations. Yes, you pass the string representation of the date to `Worksheet.Name`. Yes, you can cache that string representation if you think that will improve performance. But you should treat that string representation as dead final data. All manipulations must be done to the actual `Date` that was formatted to produce that string representation.

Comment: Right so 'CDate' is supposed to format a string as a date, but I think I see what ur saying about using string as final data, don't use previous DateStr to generate new  date variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was `CDate` wasn't transforming my date correctly based on my systems default date format. I created a variable for today in date format and used that to generate yesterdays variable.

Eg:

```
Public Sub SetDateVars()
 TdDate = Date
 TdStr = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
 YtdDate = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, TdDate))
 YtdStr = Format(YtdDate, "DD-MM-YY")
 
 Debug.Print TdDate
 Debug.Print TdStr
 Debug.Print YtdDate
 Debug.Print YtdStr
End Sub
```

Result:

```
9/13/2020 
13-09-20
9/12/2020
12-09-20
```